# playing continues audio on pages

Tags: html, audio

Sorry if it been ask before, but I just did not find it.

I know how play audio with the html5 tag, my problem is that I have multiple pages and when I move from one to another the audio start from the begin.

How I can start the audio only ones and keep it playing when I move between the pages and not start over on each page?

Answer (score 0):

try use frameset with 2 cols. 1 for audio with 0% size, and the other is 100% for displaying content. I've tried it a long time ago and it works, the sound will play continously even when moving page. But, the ugly thing is the url in browser will not change.

Comment: Thanks, the problem I need to change the urls, it is different pages.